# Mittag-Leffler fractions for $\cot^2z$ and $\frac{1}{\sin^2\pi z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> What are the Mittag-Leffler fractions for $\cot^2z$ and $\frac{1}{\sin^2\pi z}$?

My own calculations give

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)} &=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(z-n)^2} \tag{1}\\[6pt]
\cot^2(z) &=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(z-n\pi)^2} \tag{2}
\end{align}$$
These would mean that $\cot^2z=\frac{1}{\sin^2z}$, which is obviously not true.

Comment: They have the same poles and residues.  That determines much, but not all, of the expansion.  In particular, it only determines the principal part. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem agrees with your cosecant^2 expansion.  The cotangent^2 expansion is missing the terms that are the multiplication by cos^2.  I'd make this an answer if I had time to work out the exact details.

Comment: If I know my first expansion is good then I can find the multiplication factor as $cos^2$. However I would like to know how to arrive at that not knowing the first expansion. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Oh, yeah.  The multiplication by cos^2 is just a subtraction of 1;  cos^2 = 1 - sin^2, thus cotan^2 = cosec^2 - 1.

I think these expansions are hard to do in general and with full rigor.  They don't generally converge absolutely, so you have to do some varying counterterms on each partial sum, and then take limits, and ensure that convergence at the end gives you the desired function, rather than some similar one.